# How do I modify my code to from crashing app due to empty path

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My app crashes when an empty value is passed in query.

```
db.collection.update({_id:1234},{ $pull: { "": {code:321} } })
```

**Error :**

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: An empty update path is not valid.
```

How can I handle this situation without crashing the app.

Below is my code.

```
{
            try {
                const db = client.db(dbName);
                db.collection(cName).updateOne({ _id: id }, { $pull: query }).then((err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        callBack(err);
                    } else {
                        callBack(null, result);
                    }
                });
                client.close();
            }
            catch (err) {
                callBack({
                    error: 'Unable to process the request',
                    errorMessage: err
                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: Validate the query beforehand using Json-Schema/Hapi or any other validation framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your query by simply adding if condition before passing it to the MongoDB as below:

```
{
    try {
        if(query["field"]){  // Name of field from which you wants to pull
            const db = client.db(dbName);
            db.collection(cName).updateOne({ _id: id }, { $pull: query }).then((err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    callBack(err);
                } else {
                    callBack(null, result);
                }
            });
            client.close();
        }else{
            /** QUERY NOT FOUND OR INCORRECT QUERY PASSED **/
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        callBack({
            error: 'Unable to process the request',
            errorMessage: err
        })
    }
}
```